# Insufficient information in Apple Documentation regarding iOS availability?

Tags: ios, documentation

It is not a programatic question, but ... 
I take NSArray Class Reference as an instance. I don't see any iOS version, only "Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later." etc. How do I find out which version methods can work in iOS?

Is it safe to make apps for iOS 4.0 and above? As I assume most of iPhone-owners have iOS 4.0 or above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be looking at the Mac documentation. The [iOS NSArray docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) list iOS compatibility.

But yes, 4 and above is a pretty safe range for your app.

(TIP: If you somehow end up in the wrong branch of the documentation, you can just replace the "mac" in the URL with "ios" and vice-versa to switch between them.)

<sub>(DISCLAIMER ON THE TIP I JUST GAVE: That is true at least with Apple's current URL structure. They change their URLs more often than most people get their teeth cleaned, so if you're reading this in the future and it doesn't work, just leave a comment and I'll take it out.)</sub>